# How to add one tooltip for multiple element?

Tags: html, css, jsf, tooltip

I want to add a tooltip for every cell in a table. Table contains 126 cell and I need to find a brief way to add tooltip. However each of them must have its own title. Therefore tooltip must be both for each element and customizable. Is there any way to do this, especially in PrimeFaces.
Thanks.

```
<tr>
    <td id="0-0" onclick="locationClick(this)" class="table_cell" > info1 <br/> <span class="table_cell_line2">#{preparedProgramBean.getSecondLineInfoOfLocation(0,0)}</span></td>
    <td id="0-1" onclick="locationClick(this)" class="table_cell" > info2 <br/> <span class="table_cell_line2">#{preparedProgramBean.getSecondLineInfoOfLocation(0,1)}</span></td>
    <td id="0-2" onclick="locationClick(this)" class="table_cell" > info3 <br/> <span class="table_cell_line2">#{preparedProgramBean.getSecondLineInfoOfLocation(0,2)}</span></td>
    <td id="0-3" onclick="locationClick(this)" class="table_cell" > info4 <br/> <span class="table_cell_line2">#{preparedProgramBean.getSecondLineInfoOfLocation(0,3)}</span></td>
    <td id="0-4" onclick="locationClick(this)" class="table_cell" > info5 <br/> <span class="table_cell_line2">#{preparedProgramBean.getSecondLineInfoOfLocation(0,4)}</span></td>
    <td id="0-5" onclick="locationClick(this)" class="table_cell" > info6 <br/> <span class="table_cell_line2">#{preparedProgramBean.getSecondLineInfoOfLocation(0,5)}</span></td>
    <td id="0-6" onclick="locationClick(this)" class="table_cell" > info7 <br/> <span class="table_cell_line2">#{preparedProgramBean.getSecondLineInfoOfLocation(0,6)}</span></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Are you going to load the tool tips content from DB?or from an array of tool tips or any thing else please say from where are you going to load the tool tips content?

Comment: From managed bean

Comment: From an array of course objects. Brief names of course are displayed in table and tooltip should display whole name.

Comment: How is this jsf related?

Comment: @Kukeltje info comes from backing bean like this #{preparedProgramBean.getSecondLineInfoOfLocation(0,0)}

Answer (score 2):

so what i have done is generated tooltip using pseudo element and content of tooltip is from 'data-tip' attribute of corresponding `td` element

```css
td:hover:after {
  content: attr(data-tip);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

td:after {
  display: none;
}

td {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
  <table>
<tr>
    <td id="0-0" onclick="locationClick(this)" class="table_cell" data-tip="one1"  > info1 <br/> <span class="table_cell_line2">#{preparedProgramBean.getSecondLineInfoOfLocation(0,0)}</span></td>
    <td id="0-1" onclick="locationClick(this)" class="table_cell" data-tip="one2"> info2 <br/> <span class="table_cell_line2">#{preparedProgramBean.getSecondLineInfoOfLocation(0,1)}</span></td>
    <td id="0-2" onclick="locationClick(this)" class="table_cell" data-tip="one3"> info3 <br/> <span class="table_cell_line2">#{preparedProgramBean.getSecondLineInfoOfLocation(0,2)}</span></td>
    <td id="0-3" onclick="locationClick(this)" class="table_cell" data-tip="one4"> info4 <br/> <span class="table_cell_line2">#{preparedProgramBean.getSecondLineInfoOfLocation(0,3)}</span></td>
    <td id="0-4" onclick="locationClick(this)" class="table_cell" data-tip="one5"> info5 <br/> <span class="table_cell_line2">#{preparedProgramBean.getSecondLineInfoOfLocation(0,4)}</span></td>
    <td id="0-5" onclick="locationClick(this)" class="table_cell" data-tip="one6"> info6 <br/> <span class="table_cell_line2">#{preparedProgramBean.getSecondLineInfoOfLocation(0,5)}</span></td>
    <td id="0-6" onclick="locationClick(this)" class="table_cell" data-tip="one7"> info7 <br/> <span class="table_cell_line2">#{preparedProgramBean.getSecondLineInfoOfLocation(0,6)}</span></td>
</tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Is there any way to use one tooltip for all cells? Primefaces has a solution but ıt does not solve my problem completely

Comment: apply on tr tag, i mean just have that `data-tip` attribute on `tr` tag

Comment: Primefaces uses such an extra element for tooltip http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/tooltip/tooltipOptions.xhtml

Comment: Can I use id of elements to recognise themn in one tooltip?

Comment: May be, but  how?

Answer (score 0):

In PrimeFaces, you can use a [`<p:tooltip />`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/tooltip/tooltipOptions.xhtml) with the attribute `globalSelector` ([added](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/commit/5cbc41637b784301b9b04e29577729fddb30af16) in PF 4.0). For the selector, I would suggest putting a marker CSS class on all of the elements that you want to give the tooltip.

```
<p:tooltip globalSelector=".special-tooltip" />

<p:inputText styleClass="special-tooltip" title="Input 1" />
<p:inputText styleClass="special-tooltip" title="Input 2" />
```